# Open Web view when file is opened

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We are in process of creating a new file extension for vs-code ( like say - `.newFileExt`).

And whenever, file is opened, we parse the data of file and show a custom webview. So, file might contain XML tags which we read once file is opened and then create a custom HTML around it to show in webview.

I was following this example of using webview in vs code extentions:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/webview-sample/README.md

Now, the web view is called when we execute a command. However, is there any way :

- To get 'open file' handler and open our webview after parsing the data of file ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for this upcoming "custom editor view" API:

- [Custom editor view exploration (#77131)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77131)
- [Prototyping custom editors (#77789)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/77789)

It looks like this will be available as a ["proposed API"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api) in the september release.

Comment: thank you for your help. I will try it out and let you know. :)